# How to write letter as caption in image instead of Figure word

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage, subcaption

I am showing four figures in my paper, My code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}
   
    \includegraphics[width=0.90\linewidth]{figs/Upset.png}
    \caption{a}
    \label{fig:stasdet0}
    \vspace{2ex}
  \end{minipage}%%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=.90\linewidth]{figs/Upset.png} 
    \label{fig:stasdet1}
    \vspace{2ex}
  \end{minipage} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=.90\linewidth]{figs/Upset.png} 
    \label{fig:stasdet2}
    \vspace{2ex}
  \end{minipage}%% 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=.90\linewidth]{figs/Upset.png}
    \label{fig:stasdet3}
    \vspace{2ex}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{ \footnotesize (a)a_b length (b) b_c length (c) c_d length (d) d_e length }
  
  \label{fig:stasdet}
\end{figure}
```

Which is producing the figure like this:

[image]

I want to give each figure a name like `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, `(d)` but if I am using `\caption{}` it's showing `Figure 1:` text. How I can use simply `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, `(d)` instead of `Figure 1:`,`Figure 2:`,`Figure 3:`,`Figure 4:` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you load the `subcaption` package and replace all 4 `minipage` environments with `subfigure` environments and provide `\caption` directives before each `\label` instruction. Basically, a `subfigure` environment *is* a `minipage` environment that knows what to do if it encounters a `\caption` directive. By the way, do also provide information in each caption, i.e., don't write `\caption{}`.

I would also change the widths of the `subfigure` environments -- from `0.5\linewidth` to `0.475\linewidth` -- and of the embedded graphs -- from `0.9\linewidth` to `\linewidth`. And, by all means, do get rid of all four cryptic `\vspace` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}     % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}     % for 'subfigure' environment

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\linewidth}  % why do you specify the 'b' placement option?
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Upseta.png}
    \caption{a\_b length} 
    \label{fig:stasdet0}   
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Upsetb.png} 
    \caption{b\_c length}
    \label{fig:stasdet1}   
  \end{subfigure} 

  \bigskip % provide some vertical separation
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Upsetc.png} 
    \caption{c\_d length}
    \label{fig:stasdet2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill  % maximize the horizontal separation
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Upsetd.png}
    \caption{d\_e length}
    \label{fig:stasdet3} 
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{A figure with four subfigures}
  \label{fig:stasdet}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```